# CakePHP 2.1 Measuring Page Execution Time

Tags: time, execution, cakephp-1.2

How can I Measure the Page Execution Time in CakePHP 2.1?
In 1.3 it was rendered in the code when in debug mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [DebugKit Plugin](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) to find out execution time.

Or you can edit index.php in app/ and add:

```
// top of file
$starTime = microtime(true);
// bottom of file
echo '<!-- Exec time: ', microtime(true) - $startTime, ' -->';
```

That time will be in microseconds so you could convert it to ms if you want, but DebugKit gives you a lot more information.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the time returned from microtime is actually in seconds not microseconds according to the docs.