# cakePHP - function which can be called after any controller action executes

Tags: php, cakephp, callback

I need a function which can be called after any controller method executes.

Forexample, `beforeFilter()` in App controller is always called before any controller action is executed, similarly I need something like `afterFilter()`.

The problem with `afterFilter()` is that is executing before the controller action.

I have a controller name `TestController` and an action `test()`, with the following code:

**TestController.php**

```
function test() {
    echo 'test';exit;
}
```

And inside `afterFilter()` I put this code:

**AppController.php**

```
function afterFilter() {
    echo 'afterfilter';exit;
}
```

then only `afterFilter()` executes.

On commenting the above line, as follows:

```
function afterFilter() {
    //echo 'afterfilter';exit;
}
```

`TestController:test()` executes. So `afterFilter()` is getting called before the controller method. I need a function which is called after it, irrespective of the controller name or action name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `register_shutdown_function()` in php. That does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::afterFilter):

> `Controller::afterFilter()`
>
> Called after every controller action, and after rendering is complete. This is the last controller method to run.

Your `AppController::afterFilter()` callback is working as expected. You might think it's being called before `TestController::test()` because you are not able to see any output on your browser.

Try this:

```
function afterFilter() {
    echo 'afterfilter';
    echo $this->response;
    exit();
}
```

Comment: the page renders twice, i want to execute some code after the page render

Comment: And I am having one problem, for the urls which are not defined in routes.php, are not getting passed through AppController filters

Comment: You are not supposed to call `echo $this->response;`. It's just to prove my point. Whatever you include in `afterFilter()` will be the last thing to execute.

Comment: yeah but when I echo something from afterFilter, it is echoed on top the page, which means it is echoing before the page render

Comment: Don't confuse *rendering the view*, with *displaying the view*. The view is already rendered, but not displayed. If you tell me what you are trying to achieve in `afterFilter()`, perhaps I can provide some hints.

Comment: i am trying to know the execution time of page , i.e. start to end

Comment: Measuring the time between `beforeFilter()` and `afterFilter()` is an option. However, there are other metrics you may want to consider. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243141/cakephp-2-1-measuring-page-execution-time). DebugKit provides around 14 different metrics. If you are interested in the implementation, you can take a look at the source code.

Comment: Few requests have exit; in the functions, so they don't reach the after filter()

Comment: Nothing will make it to `afterFilter()` if you include `exit()` (which is equivalent to `die()`) inside an action. `exit()`should be used for debugging purposes only, and never within a normal CakePHP request. 

Getting back to the original question, I confirm that `afterFilter()` is the last callback to be executed. I think this pretty much answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are searching for are [dispatch filters](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html).